# spring boot cannot find static file w/ mustache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, oauth, mustache

i'm studying spring boot with mustache.

i use multi module with java and kotlin.

first module is java module.

second module is kotlin module that is exactly same with java module.

i study java book and than try to convert to kotlin.

i cannot find static file from kotlin module.

but works fine in java module. only kotlin module is not work well.

how to solve this problem?

here is my project [github](https://github.com/jalhagosipo/springboot-alone/releases/tag/v3.0).

i have an additional question. Is it possible to have a template and js file as a common module and use it in java and kotlin module?

Comment: hi @blahbah, may I suggest that you will be more specific and provide logs/error and code snippets around the relevant issue

Comment: @Haim Raman sorry to say this. i can't see any error. so i don't know what's wrong with it. i figure out that i can't access js file by url.

Comment: I think the issue is that java path is /jalhagosipo/springboot-alone/tree/master/java-api/src/main/resources/static/js/app while kotlin is https://github.com/jalhagosipo/springboot-alone/tree/master/kotlin-api/src/main/resources/static.js.app note the use of static.js.app vs static/js/app

Comment: @Haim Raman wow!!!!!! thank you to let me know!! i didn't notice that path is wrong!! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a wrong path.

The package name was `static.js.app` and Kotlin couldn't find the location `static/js/app/file`.

Thank you to let me know @HaimRaman